# Make Local folder .Htaccess import global rules from Root .Htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a special folder in my website that needs to have it's own routing rules.
So I have its own `.htaccess` file with the following code:

```
DirectoryIndex router.php
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /categories/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/*([^/]*/?[^/]*)/*$ router.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/*$ catrouter.php?url=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L,QSA]
```

**But with this setup, my root `.htaccess` rules are not working.**
For example, redirection from non-www to www and from non-https to https.

Here is my root structure:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdom\. [NC]

###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
###

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(BADBOT1|BADBOT2) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?na\.jpg)$ /img/image.jpg [L,NC,QSA]


# Add Proper MIME-Type for Favicon
AddType image/x-icon .ico

# BEGIN EXPIRES
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

How can I make this special `.htaccess` to follow the other rules that are set by default by the root `.htaccess`?

Alternatively, how should I copy the rules from root into the special one, in a way that it will work properly?

Comment: Your root htaccess doesnt apply to your special folder because it has its own htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your server is reading htaccess rules from `/category` folder not  the root.  Your `/category/.htaccess` is called when you request something from the server with `/category` URI .  You need to copy the `http to https` rule from your root/htaccess and paste it into `/category/.htaccess` in order for the https redirection to work .

```
 DirectoryIndex router.php
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
#force ssl plus www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
####
RewriteBase /categories/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/*([^/]*/?[^/]*)/*$ router.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/*$ catrouter.php?url=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What about all the EXPIRE rules and blocking bad bots? should they be copied as well?

Comment: @rockyraw yes you will need to copy all the rules and directive you need for the `/category` folder . I forgot to mention in my answer you can also use `RewriteOptions inherit` directive a singe line in your htaccess  see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868763/what-does-rewriteoptions-inherit-in-htaccess-file-do

Comment: simply `Options inherit` instead of all the blocks? then why not do that? this way when I modify root later I don't need to worry about such folders. are there any cons to this? can you show me in which line of the code should I add that line, in order for anything to work properly?

Comment: @rockyraw Thats correct. Put this just bellow 
The `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: It does not work. If I put it below that line. Everything remain the same. Also, if this is inheriting only the Rewrite, this mean it will not handle the `ExpiresByType` directives in any way.. right? (and rather only the bad bots)

Comment: @Rockyraw `RewriteOptions` directive inherits `RewriteRules` only . Only `mod-rewrite` rules are affected by this not other modules.

Comment: Still, none of the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule ` rules in my code are being inherited, unless I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: I tried, still does not work :( Is there a way to do everything from root htaccess without using htaccess to this folder?

Comment: @rockyraw If you want your parent htaccess rules to apply to your `/category` folder then delete the htaccess file in your `/category` folder.

Comment: yeah but how do i apply the custom rules only to the category folder, straight from the root htaccess?